# Select a special div with CSS

Tags: css

If I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="profile-header col-sm-4">
    <div class="profile-cover">
        <h1>01</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I select the `div.checkbox` in CSS ?

I tried:

```
.profile-cover > .checkbox
```

I do not want to be too large by selecting `.checkbox`.

Thanks.

Comment: `.profile-cover .checkbox.checkbox-primary` or just `.profile-cover .checkbox-primary` or `.profile-cover .checkbox` if it is not too vast of a selection

Comment: `>` means a direct parent-child relationship, which you don't have here. `.profile-cover .checkbox-primary` should do, if you don't want to get too specific either ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A > B` only selects a child (direct descendant), so it sounds like you just need:

```
.profile-cover .checkbox
```

Which means `.checkbox` anywhere inside `.profile-cover`.

Answer (score 0):

sorted in descending order of accuracy (all will hit your targeted element):

```
.profile-header>.profile-cover>.row>.col-sm-6>div.checkbox,
.profile-header>.profile-cover>.row div.checkbox,
.profile-header>.profile-cover div.checkbox,
.profile-header div.checkbox,
.profile-cover div.checkbox
```